# how to translate unicode character with c# google translate

Tags: c#, unicode, translate

I have a c# program that uses google translate to translate text from one language to another. however, it cannot translate the "<" or ">" characters

<买/@buy>防具\

translates as: \u003cBuy/@buy\u003eArmor\

the wanted result is: **<**Buy/@buy**>** Armor\

this is the code part

```
                    translation = translation.Trim();
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ?", "?");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" !", "!");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ,", ",");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" .", ".");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ;", ";");
                    translation = translation.Replace("\\u003cbr\\u003e", "\r\n"); //ymy
```

this is the full source code:

```
public string Translate
            (string sourceText,
             string sourceLanguage,
             string targetLanguage)
        {
            // Initialize
            this.Error = null;
            this.TranslationSpeechUrl = null;
            this.TranslationTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
            DateTime tmStart = DateTime.Now;
            string translation = string.Empty;
            ConvertToGoogle(ref sourceText); //ymy

            try {
                // Download translation
                string url = string.Format ("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={0}&tl={1}&dt=t&q={2}",
                                            Translator.LanguageEnumToIdentifier (sourceLanguage),
                                            Translator.LanguageEnumToIdentifier (targetLanguage),
                                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode (sourceText));
                string outputFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient ()) {
                    wc.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
                    wc.DownloadFile(url, outputFile);
                }

                // Get translated text
                if (File.Exists (outputFile)) {

                    // Get phrase collection
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(outputFile);
                    int index = text.IndexOf (string.Format(",,\"{0}\"", Translator.LanguageEnumToIdentifier (sourceLanguage)));
                    if (index == -1) {
                        // Translation of single word
                        int startQuote = text.IndexOf('\"');
                        if (startQuote != -1) {
                            int endQuote = text.IndexOf('\"', startQuote + 1);
                            if (endQuote != -1) {
                                translation = text.Substring(startQuote + 1, endQuote - startQuote - 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // Translation of phrase
                        text = text.Substring(0, index);
                        text = text.Replace("],[", ",");
                        text = text.Replace("]", string.Empty);
                        text = text.Replace("[", string.Empty);
                        text = text.Replace("\",\"", "\"");
                    // Get translated phrases
                    string[] phrases = text.Split (new[] { '\"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        for (int i=0; (i < phrases.Count()); i += 2) {
                            string translatedPhrase = phrases[i];
                            if (translatedPhrase.StartsWith(",,")) {
                                i--;
                                continue;
                            }
                            translation += translatedPhrase + "  ";
                        }
                    }

                    // Fix up translation
                    translation = translation.Trim();
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ?", "?");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" !", "!");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ,", ",");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" .", ".");
                    translation = translation.Replace(" ;", ";");
                    translation = translation.Replace("\\u003cbr\\u003e", "\r\n"); //ymy
                // And translation speech URL
                this.TranslationSpeechUrl = string.Format ("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl={1}&total=1&idx=0&textlen={2}&client=gtx",
                                                               HttpUtility.UrlEncode (translation), Translator.LanguageEnumToIdentifier (targetLanguage), translation.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                this.Error = ex;
            }

            // Return result
            this.TranslationTime = DateTime.Now - tmStart;
            return translation;
        }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a language to its identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="language">The language."</param>
        /// <returns>The identifier or <see cref="string.Empty"/> if none.</returns>
        private static string LanguageEnumToIdentifier
            (string language)
        {
            string mode = string.Empty;
            Translator.EnsureInitialized();
            Translator._languageModeMap.TryGetValue (language, out mode);
            return mode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures the translator has been initialized.
        /// </summary>
        private static void EnsureInitialized()
        {
            if (Translator._languageModeMap == null) {
                Translator._languageModeMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Afrikaans",   "af");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Albanian",    "sq");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Arabic",      "ar");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Armenian",    "hy");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Azerbaijani", "az");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Basque",      "eu");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Belarusian",  "be");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Bengali",     "bn");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Bulgarian",   "bg");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Catalan",     "ca");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Chinese",     "zh-CN");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Croatian",    "hr");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Czech",       "cs");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Danish",      "da");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Dutch",       "nl");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("English",     "en");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Esperanto",   "eo");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Estonian",    "et");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Filipino",    "tl");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Finnish",     "fi");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("French",      "fr");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Galician",    "gl");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("German",      "de");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Georgian",    "ka");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Greek",       "el");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Haitian Creole",    "ht");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Hebrew",      "iw");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Hindi",       "hi");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Hungarian",   "hu");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Icelandic",   "is");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Indonesian",  "id");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Irish",       "ga");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Italian",     "it");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Japanese",    "ja");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Korean",      "ko");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Lao",         "lo");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Latin",       "la");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Latvian",     "lv");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Lithuanian",  "lt");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Macedonian",  "mk");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Malay",       "ms");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Maltese",     "mt");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Norwegian",   "no");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Persian",     "fa");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Polish",      "pl");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Portuguese",  "pt");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Romanian",    "ro");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Russian",     "ru");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Serbian",     "sr");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Slovak",      "sk");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Slovenian",   "sl");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Spanish",     "es");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Swahili",     "sw");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Swedish",     "sv");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Tamil",       "ta");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Telugu",      "te");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Thai",        "th");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Turkish",     "tr");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Ukrainian",   "uk");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Urdu",         "ur");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Vietnamese",  "vi");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Welsh",       "cy");
                Translator._languageModeMap.Add ("Yiddish",     "yi");
            }
        }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The language to translation mode map.
        /// </summary>
        private static Dictionary<string, string> _languageModeMap;

    #endregion


    #region Update
    private void ConvertToGoogle(ref string para)
    {
        para = para.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");

    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you see the text `\u003cBuy/@buy\u003eArmor\` ?

Comment: It's on a output text box. Input text box source language and output text box target language